# How to skip telling a service/process to stop if it is already stopped

Tags: c#

I am building an App to uninstall a program.

First I need to get all associated services and Processes to stop.

After some trial and error I have created the following command:

---

///Stop SQL and Act service

```
        List<string> servicesList = new List<string>{
            "ACT! Service Host",
            "ACT! Smart Task Service Host",
            "ActConnectLink",
            "SQL Server (ACT7)",
            "SQL Server Browser",
            "Act! Scheduler",
            "APFWLicensingSrvc"
        };

        foreach (string serviceName in servicesList)


        {
            StopRunningService(serviceName);
        }


    private void StopRunningService(string name)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(name);
        if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        {
            service.Stop();
        }

    }
```

---

The only problem with this, is that if a service is already stopped or does not exist (as this is App will be to remove 3 slightly different versions of software made by my company so some will have some API features and services and some wont), then the test fails and i get:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Service "Service name" was not found on computer '.'.'

So I want to introduce an "If" command to help it get past the problem.

Something like "If service is found and is running", then have it continue with stopping the service.

From that I can then figure out how to do the same thing with processes.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: what is ServiceController?

Comment: put a try catch round it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably make use of [`ServiceController.GetServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.getservices?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Retrieves the non-device driver services on a computer, and those that
>   are not drivers.

```
var services = ServiceController.GetServices(machineName);

var servicesList = new List<string>
                        {
                           "ACT! Service Host",
                           "ACT! Smart Task Service Host",
                           "ActConnectLink",
                           "SQL Server (ACT7)",
                           "SQL Server Browser",
                           "Act! Scheduler",
                           "APFWLicensingSrvc"
                        };

var activeServices = services.Where(x => servicesList.Contains(x.ServiceName) && x.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
foreach (var service in activeServices)
{
   try
   {
      service.Stop();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      // maybe log something here
   }
}
```

***Note*** : I am not professing this is the solve to all your problems and is a clean cut solution. I am just pointing out how to get the names and filter known services